# Переопределение ссылок

Tags: c++, ссылки

В учебнике написано, что любая ссылка должна быть определена в момент объявления, и определена объектом, а не литералом. И её нельзя перевязать на другой объект. Из любопытства сделал следующее:

```
{
int val = 20,val2 = 2;
int &refVal = val;
refVal = val2;
cout<<refVal<<endl;
 system("PAUSE");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

И к моему удивлению, на выходе ссылка ссылается на переменную val2, в консоли выводит двойку. Как так, это от компилятора зависит? Либо автор не прав. Можно ссылку на официальную документацию? Это вообще нормально?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Дело в том, что ссылка это просто синтаксический сахар над указателями, поэтому, если переписать Ваш код через них, должно быть понятно, что происходит:

```
{
    int val = 20,val2 = 2;
    int*const refVal = &val;
    *refVal = val2;
    cout<<*refVal<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Заметьте, в коде выше мы лишь единожды инициализируем указатель, а потом уже всюду его разыменовываем, не меняя его, но меняя тот объект, на который он указывает. Так вот, ссылка, будучи инициализирована, не может быть изменена, это просто *синтаксически невозможно*. Любое последующее использование ссылки является обращением к тому объекту, на который она ссылается(разыменование указателя в моём примеру).

Comment: Да, да, и вам спасибо. Я уже всё понял. Просто нужно было немного подумать.

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка это второе имя (псевдоним) переменной. Именно потому она обязательно должна быть определена: вторым именем можно быть только если есть первое. Учитывая что в с++ любой тип данных - класс, и любая переменная объект - ваш код не противоречит словам автора. Под литералом видимо подразумевалось строковая константа. (например "myLit")

Comment: А, стоп, я всё понял, я получается присвоил переменной val значение 2,  получается я не перевязал ссылку, а просто присвоил значение объекту на который она указывает. Чтобы перевязать ссылку нужно писать так &refVal, таким образом изменяется её содержимое, а именно адрес. При такой записи компилятор ругается, что ожидаемо.Всё, спасибо вам. Думаю вопрос закрыт)

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirovich И здесь вы не правы, выражение `&refVal` возвращает адрес исходного объекта, а не содержимое ссылки. Единожды создав ссылку изменить ее вы не сможете, вообще никак. Все операции выполняются над исходным объектом.

Comment: @Cerbo Это я наверное с указателями немного их перепутал)

Comment: @Mira  `Учитывая что в с++ любой тип данных - класс` что?? int не class - это вам не C# молодой человек

Comment: Не паникуйте %) есть такое мнение. Любой класс - считается полноценным типом, (а тип по сути класс). И структура - класс, и union - класс. Вы же можете сделать new int - а ведь функция new - определена для классов

Comment: @Mira я ещё не очень разбираюсь, но для меня странно звучит то что класса, как я понимаю, с названием int нет, но переменная типа int является объектом) как это понимать? Просто один термин используют для обозначения разных элементов языка?

Comment: Ну это "грубо говоря", чтобы понимать как располагается на стеке/в куче, указатели-ссылки и прочее - можно считать что все переменные - это объекты. Т.к. после создания класс является полноценным типом данных, получается что любой объект класса - это переменная типа. Вот смотрите - вы можете написать так Int i(4); то есть вызвать конструктор класса int инициализирующий объект i числом 4

Comment: @Mira верно, спасибо за разъяснения, после java всё это немного непривычно, хотя там тоже всё - классы)

Comment: Mira, Вы путаете понятия, в C++ у класса есть чёткое определение в стандарте, не стоит его использовать не по назначению. int не является классом и у него нет никакого конструктора. Но, да, все переменные в C++ являются объектами, а объект это storage location, это не тот объект, что в ООП и не тот, что в Java&C#. //CC @AlexeyVladimirovich